# Separate method or modify existing for functionality

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

I'm building method `Convert` to turn `string` of zeroes and ones into `int`:

```cs
public int Convert(string binaryString)
{
    ValidateOrThrow(binaryString);

    return ConvertInternal(binaryString); // Peforms convertion.
}
```

This method runs validation for provided string:

```cs
private void ValidateOrThrow(string binaryString)
{
    if (binaryString is null || binaryString.Length == 0)
        throw new InvalidDataException("Can't convert null or empty string");

    if (binaryString.Any(value => (byte)value is not 48 or 49))
        throw new InvalidDataException("Can't convert non-binary string");
}
```

Now I want to add new method `TryConvert` which returns `bool` as the result of `Valdate` instead of throwing an exception.

```cs
public bool TryConvert(string binaryString, out int result)
{
    if (!Validate(binaryString))
        return false;

    result = ConvertInternal(binaryString);
    return true;
}
```

I can create one more method `Validate` with `bool` return type, but it breaks `DRY`.

Or I can create single parameterized method and use it in both cases with different parameter:

```cs
private bool Validate(string binaryString, bool throwOnInvalidData)
{
    if (binaryString is null || binaryString.Length == 0)
    {
        if (throwOnInvalidData)
            throw new InvalidDataException("Can't convert null or empty string");
        else
            return false;
    }

    if (binaryString.Any(value => (byte)value is not 48 or 49))
    {
        if (throwOnInvalidData)
            throw new InvalidDataException("Can't convert non-binary string");
        else
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Is this valid way or I'm missing something?

Comment: In this case, I think what makes sense would be to have your validate method how you have it in the first example. Leave the convert method alone as well. In your TryConvert, wrap a call to the convert method in a try/catch. If an exception is thrown, return false, otherwise, return the result of convert.

Comment: @emagers no, the "try" version should not rely on `try/catch` semantics as if you do that you completely throw away the whole point of the `try` version which is to not incur the overhead of exceptions.

Comment: I believe the idiomatic solution here is to make the `TryConvert` method the source of truth and have the version that throws the exception simply throw if `TryConvert` returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the nested `if` statements in your validate.  What if you gave it an out parameter too -

```
private bool Validate(string binaryString, out string error)
{
     error = null;
     if (binaryString is null || binaryString.Length == 0)
     {
         error = "Can't convert null or empty string";
         return false;
     }

     if (binaryString.Any(value => (byte)value is not 48 or 49))
     {
          error = "Can't convert non-binary string";
          return false;
     }

     return true;
}
```

Then you have two methods that use it -

```
public int Convert(string binaryString)
{
    if(!Validate(binaryString, out var error))
    {
        throw new InvalidDataException(error);
    }

    return ConvertInternal(binaryString);
}
```

and

```
public bool TryConvert(string binaryString, out int result)
{
    result = 0;

    if (!Validate(binaryString, out var error))
    {
        return false;
    }

    result = ConvertInternal(binaryString);
    return true;
}
```